# How to get the entire row data based on a Max value for a column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function siradaki() {
  var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('.sira').map(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  }))
  
  alert(high);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Lastname</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Value</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Deneme</td>
    <td>SDeneme</td>
    <td class="sira">100</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Ornek</td>
    <td>SOrnek</td>
    <td class="sira">150</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button name="siradaki" id="siradaki" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="siradaki();">Sıradaki Kim ?</button>
```

This code works. But how can I get `Name` and `Lastname` along with max `Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab all rows instead of just a value from `.sira` cell and then analyze them. That way you will have full info when you find max.

```js
function siradaki() {
  var max = -Infinity;
  var maxRow;
  $('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($('.sira', this).text(), 10);
    if (value > max) {
      max = value;
      maxRow = $(this);
    }
  });

  alert(maxRow.text());
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th style="width:10%;">Name</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Lastname</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Deneme</td>
      <td>SDeneme</td>
      <td class="sira">100</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Ornek</td>
      <td>SOrnek</td>
      <td class="sira">150</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

<button name="siradaki" id="siradaki" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="siradaki();">Sıradaki Kim ?</button>

</html>
```

Comment: And how would it be if i want to take the minimum value

Comment: Rename variables appropriately, set initial value to `+Infinity` and flip the conditional for `less` sign. But on your place I would create a separate function for that.

Comment: u are the best and do you have something to learn easily jquery

Comment: Try this: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-jquery/lessons/jquery-setup/exercises/why-jquery?action=resume_content_item - interactive step by step guide. This (and some more) are free.

Comment: Thank you and last thing sorry i'm taking ur time but if there is same two values how can i get two of them

Comment: i cant do the logic no matter i think i cant find a solution for that

Comment: Here's the hint: `each`, `map` and other iterator methods receive index and the item as their arguments. You can store matching ones `max === value` in the array and then access it in the end. Do not forget to reset the array, if you find new max.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.siblings` to get the sibling `td` elements and `.textContent` to get their text. Store them in a string and alert them with the high

```js
 var str='';
function siradaki(){
           var high = Math.max.apply(Math, $('tr > .sira').map(function(){
          var a=Object.values($(this).siblings())
           str=a[0].textContent+ " " + a[1].textContent;
                   return $(this).text();
 
})) 
alert (str + " " +high );
   }
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Lastname</th>
   <th style="width:10%;">Value</th>
</tr>
 
<tr> 
<td>Deneme</td>
<td>SDeneme</td>
<td class="sira">100</td>
<tr>

<tr> 
<td>Ornek</td>
<td>SOrnek</td>
<td class="sira">150</td>
<tr>

</table>

<button name="siradaki" id="siradaki" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="siradaki();">Sıradaki Kim ?</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function siradaki(){

var value = $('tr td').map(function () {
return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
}).get();

var high = Math.max.apply(Math, value);
alert(high);
 }
```

try this dont add class grab all rows

Answer (score 0):

try to sort a list by value in desc order, and get the first object from the list

```js
function siradaki() {
      var high = $('.sira').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text() < $(b).text()
      })[0];
      
      console.log($(high).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text());
console.log($(high).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
console.log($(high).text());
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Lastname</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Value</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Deneme</td>
    <td>SDeneme</td>
    <td class="sira">100</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Ornek</td>
    <td>SOrnek</td>
    <td class="sira">150</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button name="siradaki" id="siradaki" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="siradaki();">Sıradaki Kim ?</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```js
function siradaki() {
var arr = [];
  $('.sira').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).text());
    var Names = $(this).siblings('td').text();
    console.log('Names: '+ Names);
  })
  
  var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);

  console.log('maxValue: '+maxValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:10%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Lastname</th>
    <th style="width:10%;">Value</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Deneme</td>
    <td>SDeneme</td>
    <td class="sira">100</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Ornek</td>
    <td>SOrnek</td>
    <td class="sira">150</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button name="siradaki" id="siradaki" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="siradaki();">Sıradaki Kim ?</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this siblings method of jQuery here - https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

You can access siblings using **tr** tag as the parameters and distinguish the first name and the last name using index i.e. 0 for first and 1 for last name.